What is causing Elementor video header fallback image from loading because of this code?
Below is the code that is preventing the fallback image from loading. It's pulling selected choices from an ACF field and displaying them on a post template.  Any insight on what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated!
function populate_outdoor_rec_poi_select_field( $field ) {
  
  $field[ 'choices' ] = array();
    
  $rec_poi_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'point-of-interest',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all points of interest
    )
  );

  if ( $rec_poi_query->have_posts() ): 
    while ( $rec_poi_query->have_posts() ): 
        $rec_poi_query->the_post();
            $options_name = get_field('poi_map_link');
            $field[ 'choices' ][ get_field('poi_map_link') ] = get_the_title();
    endwhile;
  endif;
  sort( $field[ 'choices' ] );
  return $field;
}
add_filter( 'acf/load_field/name=outdoor_rec_points_of_interest', 'populate_outdoor_rec_poi_select_field' );

